# Why is my certificate not being validated?

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, x509

I have a certificate server on a network with two servers that come before it in the chain, so when I view the Certification Path of my certificate in MMC, I see two certificates above it. Originally, validating this certificate did not work because there was an error with revocation during my custom validator using the X509Chain.Build() method. So, since I realized my generated certificate did not contain any CRL distribution points, I made the certificate server generate them, so now using the checkbox, "Include in the CDP extension of issued certificates" in my certificate server, the certificate server generates an HTTP CRL distribution point for this certificate and I see it. I can even access the URL it contains and download the CRL file. The problem now, is that while I try validating this certificate in my service application running under the local system account, I get the following error in the X509Chain.ChainStatus list after issuing an X509Chain build:

```
Status: OfflineRevocation
StatusInformation: The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
```

Using a console application running under my administrator account, I get the following error:

```
Status: RevocationStatusUnknown
StatusInformation: The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

Does anyone have some ideas on what I can try next to get revocation to work for my certificate so that I can actually validate it? I don't seem to have any issues pinging my certificate server, either.

Comment: First try running certutil on your certificate to verify your certificate and to see details on what CDPs it's accessing and details on the error. For an example see: admin-enclave.com/en/tutorials/windows/57-how-to-verify-the-certificate-chain-via ... maybe your "server" certificates CDPs can't be accessed...they don't have an HTTP CRL distribution point (maybe trying to go through LDAP)?

Comment: @colinsmith - Thanks for your answer, I have a question for you. How do I use certutil with a .pfx certificate? I tried exporting my certificate as a password-protected pfx file to the desktop and using the same command to verify it but I get the error, "CertUtil: ASN1 unexpected end of data."

Comment: Okay, I got it working by not exporting the private key, thus just exporting a .cer file...I will look into this now...

Comment: @colinsmith - Okay, I see Expired "Base CRL (01)" Time: 0 for the HTTP CRL distibution point...so does this mean that my CRL distribution point is expired and I need to publish a new one or something, and it won't use this URL because its considered to be expired? I'm really new to this whole process.

Comment: Can you post the entire output ? Also see here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7e6fe88d-d0f1-400f-a2c1-213d660f2acc/ca-certificate-authority-fails-to-start-revocation-check-failed

Comment: Maybe you need to publish a new CRL as you have an expired one: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/281ceb1f-dd57-4573-8620-1252a1430893/expired-offline-crl ... and ... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737180(v=ws.10).aspx ... and ... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782041(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Sweet, your link was exactly what I needed, just needed to right-click my revocation list and publish it! Thanks, I guess this server never had a CRL list published to it.

Comment: @colinsmith - Please submit your comment as an answer so that I may accept it as the valid solution for my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To track down your issue I suggest you use `certutil.exe` to verify your certificate and see the steps being taken. See here for an example:

- https://www.admin-enclave.com/computer/windows/how-to-verify-the-certificate-chain-via-windows

As you mentioned, your problem turned out to be with the CRL being expired. Here are some links that talk about CRLs, and how to publish/reissue them.

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/281ceb1f-dd57-4573-8620-1252a1430893/expired-offline-crl
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737180(v=ws.10).aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782041(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: For those of you out there, I also set up publish paths on the CA's extensions, so you might wanna do that too before you publish your revocation lists.

Comment: I have the same exact issue, my result from the certutil contiains Missing Issuer = "CN=testRoot8"   Incomplete certificate chain
Cannot find certificate:
    CN=testRoot8
Cannot check leaf certificate revocation status ... And no idea what I'm missing